# In 1968 there were more than 3000 programming languages known, how large would this number be today?

Tags: programming-languages

Alan Kay stated in one of his talks that there was a paper in 1968 that listen at least 3000 programming languages that were known in the year 1968.

What would be an unsientific but "educated guess" on the number of programming languages that existed up till now?

(I.e., this number would assume that if a programming language ever existed it is counted in the total number of today)

Comment: I've no idea why it wasn't displayed on the front page for you: I think it's only questions with a strongly negative score (-4 or less?) that aren't displayed.

Comment: Voting to close as not computer science; one of [so] and [programmers.se] is probably more appropriate. And, for the record, referring to people on CS Theory as "smarter", with the implication that people here are "dumber" really rubs me up the wrong way.

Comment: Would you care to define programming language. Is HTML a programming language? Is PHP? Is Scheme different from Lisp? If yes, were does Common Lisp stand? Etc ... I doubt that Kay did any serious survey to come up with this figure, or that he bothered to give it a precise meaning. But I do not have the paper for which you give no reference. It may be relevant for a sociologist possibly ... what else?  P.S.  Apologies for not being smart enough, though I occasionally answer on CStheory, where you ask questions.

Comment: think there is some real possible science/ classification behind the question. however, its probably not really studied much. more common is research on "top languages"...

Comment: The answer to this question is 42

Comment: It's difficult to count them because how to separate them it a matter of opinion. Do you count all Cs as one language? All C#s? All Visual Basics? A few thousand languages are listed at http://hopl.murdoch.edu.au/ (except that it's down).